# question about space groups

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-groups, gap

I have 2 groups, generated by 4x4 matrices such as X (x+1,y,z), Y (x,y+1,z), Z(x,y,z+1), R (-x,-y,z), F(-y,x,z).
R - 2-fold rotation matrix and F+ - 4-fold rotation matrix (counterclockwise).
Each 4x4 matrix consists of rotating matrix and translation vector in 3D-space, written in one matrix.
For example: $$ F=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1&0&0\\\ 1&0&0&0\\\ 0&0&1&0\\\ 0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$ X=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&1\\\ 0&1&0&0\\\ 0&0&1&0\\\ 0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
First group is generated from all 5 matrices (it's Fedorov group #75)
Second is generated from only X, Z and F.
Because $Y=F^{-1} * X * F$ and $R=F^{2}$ we can say that they are equal.
How can i automate process of evaluating any matrix from set of others (if it's possible), for example: try to solve Y as equation of X, Z, F.
OR
How can i compare 2 groups, generated with different generating set, is it possible to do in any linear algebra systems, such as GAP?

Comment: Hi, please use latex to type your question!

Comment: Please consider editing your question to include [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), so that it's easier to understand.

Comment: Comparing two infinite groups is a very hard problem. If you know that one of them is crystallographic, then [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org) has packages [Cryst](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/cryst.html) - Computing with crystallographic groups and [CrystCat](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/crystcat.html) - The crystallographic groups catalog. It might happen that these may help here, but I suggest to ask this in the [GAP Forum or GAP Support](http://www.gap-system.org/Contacts/Forum/forum.html) to reach package authors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing two infinite groups is a very hard problem. If you know that one of them is crystallographic, then [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) has packages [Cryst](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/cryst.html) - *Computing with crystallographic groups* and [CrystCat](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/crystcat.html) - *The crystallographic groups catalog*. It might happen that these may help here, but I suggest to ask this in the [GAP Forum or GAP Support](http://www.gap-system.org/Contacts/Forum/forum.html) to reach package authors

(Just copied here my earlier comment to remove this question from the unanswered queue).